# Merge multiple Valgrind XML output

Tags: xml, valgrind

Here's what I have right now

```
valgrind \
    --xml=yes \
    --xml-file=memory.leak.mt.%p.xml \
    --trace-children=yes \
    ./my_script.sh
```

And because of the `%p` in `--xml-file` parameter, I have quite a number of XML files per process. Now, I want to merge them in the cleanest way possible.

I would also want the "non-essential" outputs (those with no errors) to be ignored.

Anyone have any suggestions for an approach or is there already an existing approach/program for this? Last resort would probably be making a script on my own but it would take some time...

If it would be of any help, I'm currently using version 3.9.0.

TYIA! :-)